# slurm - action_unknown in pam_slurm_adopt

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, slurm, pam

What does "source job" refer to in the description of `action_unknown`?

> ```
> action_unknown
> The action to perform when the user has multiple jobs on the node
> and the RPC does not locate the **source job**. If the RPC mechanism works
> properly in your environment, this option will likely be relevant only
> when connecting from a login node. Configurable values are:
>
> newest (default)
> Pick the newest job on the node. The "newest" job is chosen based
> on the mtime of the job's step_extern cgroup; asking Slurm would
> require an RPC to the controller. Thus, the memory cgroup must be in
> use so that the code can check mtimes of cgroup directories. The user
> can ssh in but may be adopted into a job that exits earlier than the
> job they intended to check on. The ssh connection will at least be
> subject to appropriate limits and the user can be informed of better
> ways to accomplish their objectives if this becomes a problem.
>
> allow
> Let the connection through without adoption.
>
> deny
> Deny the connection.
> ```

https://slurm.schedmd.com/pam_slurm_adopt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slurm_pam_adopt` will try to capture an incoming SSH session into the `cgroup` corresponding to the job currently running on the host. This option is meant to decide what to do when there are several jobs running for the user that initiates the `ssh` command.

The 'source job' is the jobid of the process that initiates the `ssh` call. Typically, if you use an interactive `ssh` session from the frontend, there is not 'source job', but if the `ssh` command is run from within a submission script, then the 'source job' is the one corresponding to that submission script.